# How can i insert an image into the phone shell

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have an image,

[image]

I want to insert them into the phone shell like this :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

to get this :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

is there any image processing algorithms can be used to automate this process ?

I would like to have some ideas to achieve this

Comment: Are those four phone shell images set in stone? Or do you want to provide an arbitrary phone shell image and have the algorithm place the image automatically? If you only want to deal with those four images, you could set the transformation for each image that maps the input image onto the iphone pretty easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Here's a revised version with `impoly`:

```
% Read images
skull = imread('skull.jpg');
skull_mask = true(size(skull,1),size(skull,2)); % Use mask for overlay

shell = imread('shell2.jpg');
imshow(shell);
hold on;
p_h = impoly;

% Find transformation (either set this manually or find it with something
% like sift)
input_points = [0              size(skull,1); 
                size(skull,2)  size(skull,1); 
                size(skull,2)  0;
                0              0];

base_points = getPosition(p_h);

% Perform transformation
tform = cp2tform(input_points,base_points,'projective');

skull = imtransform(skull, tform, ...
                    'XData', [1 size(shell,2)], ...
                    'YData', [1 size(shell,1)], ...
                    'Size', [size(shell,1) size(shell,2)]);

skull_mask = imtransform(skull_mask, tform, ...
                         'XData', [1 size(shell,2)], ...
                         'YData', [1 size(shell,1)], ...
                         'Size', [size(shell,1) size(shell,2)]);

skull_mask = imerode(skull_mask,strel('disk',2)); % Prevents rough edges

% Overlay images
skull_r = skull(:,:,1);
skull_g = skull(:,:,2);
skull_b = skull(:,:,3);

shell_overlay_r = shell(:,:,1);
shell_overlay_g = shell(:,:,2);
shell_overlay_b = shell(:,:,3);

shell_overlay_r(skull_mask) = skull_r(skull_mask);
shell_overlay_g(skull_mask) = skull_g(skull_mask);
shell_overlay_b(skull_mask) = skull_b(skull_mask);

% Combine into one image
shell_overlay(:,:,1) = shell_overlay_r;
shell_overlay(:,:,2) = shell_overlay_g;
shell_overlay(:,:,3) = shell_overlay_b;

% Show overlay
imshow(shell_overlay);
```

If you want a robust implementation for arbitrary input shell images you will need to use something like SIFT, which I wouldn't recommend since it's difficult. I'd suggest just finding the appropriate `base_points` for a set of shell images and then you can supply any input image you want and overlay it.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Very nice. +1.  However, just to give you fair warning - `cp2tform` and `imtransform` are soon to be deprecated.  Consider using [`affine2d`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/affine2d-class.html) and [`imwarp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html) to ensure you don't use deprecated functions.

Comment: @jucestain you are a genius!
yes, the ideal is to find the transformation automatically, so I want to provide an arbitrary phone shell image and have the algorithm place the image automatically.
otherwise find the transform semi-automaticly Example (define the shell with mouse clicks) is it possible?

Comment: @user3210664 I made an edit to use `impoly`. Pretty simple. Just make sure you go over the code - it's pretty rough. There may be off by 1 errors or something but the idea is correct.